# threading error for performSegue with viewController? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I am trying to jump to a second view controller after I have authorized a user's TouchID. I am able to validate that the TouchID is working but I am having an issue of jumping to a second viewController.

I have created a SecondViewController and a Segue with the Identifier "dispenseScreen". However, whenever I try to jump to the second screen my program crashes.

```
@IBAction func touchID(_ sender: Any)
    {

        let context:LAContext = LAContext()

        //Removes Enter Password during failed TouchID
        context.localizedFallbackTitle = ""

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
        {
                context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "We require your TouchID", reply: { (wasCorrect, error) in

                self.isBiometryReady()
                if wasCorrect {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dispenseScreen", sender: self)
                    print("Correct")
                }
                else {
                    print("Incorrect")
                }
            })
        } else {
            //Enter phone password if too many login attempts
            //Add message alerting user that TouchID is not enabled
        }

    }
```

There are no semantic errors in my code but I am receiving a threading error when I try to go to the second view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do the segue in the callback from `evaluatePolicy`.  For anything involving UI, you need to make sure you're on the main thread: `(wasCorrect, error) in DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`

Comment: that worked thank you. how do I completely switch screens? It looks like the PerformSegue only brings up a "popup" window in front of the first screen

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a UIKit person.  I'd suggest making another topic if you have questions about that.